# Twitter Widget with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, widget

I've looked high and low for simple twitter widget that shows how many followers the specified account has and it's first 5 tweets but I can't find/get any of them working. Do you guys have any ideas? I tried this one http://www.themelab.com/2010/05/18/custom-twitter-widget-tutorial/
but i can't get it to work.

Comment: First five tweets and no of followers of a specified user???

Comment: @iNan Yes, that's what i'm looking for

Comment: I am a student, Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can make use of `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json` to fetch user timeline and `http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json` to get information about the particular username. Here is a sample twitter widget which i developed hope it will help you.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body{background:#ccc;}
.status{
color:#000;
}    
h3,h4{
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
text-decoration:none;
}
#txt
{
font-size: 11px;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
}
.status
{
min-height:60px;
padding:6px;
border-bottom:solid 1px #DEDEDE
font-size: 11px;
background:transparent;
border:#eaeaea 2px;
}
.status a
{
color:#3cf;
text-decoration:none
font-size: 11px;
}
.status a:hover{
color:#3cf;
text-decoration:underline
}
.twitter_image{
float:left;
margin-right:14px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
padding:3px;
}
.twitter_posted_at{
font-size:11px;
color:#999
}
#tweets{
margin:auto auto;
overflow:scroll;
background:#eaeaea;
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
</style>
<div id="tweets">
<div id = "heading"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var username = "Google";
var recentTweetsUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name="+username+"&count=15&callback=?"
var followerCountUrl ="http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name="+username+"&callback=?";
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax
({type: "GET",url: followerCountUrl,dataType:"jsonp",success: function(response)
{
fCount = response.followers_count;
var headerData = "<h3>"+username+"</h3><h4>"+fCount+"Followers on Twitter</h4>";
$(headerData).appendTo('#heading');
}
});
$.ajax
({type: "GET",url: recentTweetsUrl,dataType:"jsonp",success: function(response)
{
var tdata='';
for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
data =response[i];
var id=data.id;
var text=data.text;
var created_time=data.created_at;
var screen_name=data.user.screen_name;
var image=data.user.profile_image_url;
var source=data.source;
tdata+="<div class='status' id='"+id+"'><img src="+image+" class='twitter_image'/><a href='http://twitter.com/"+screen_name+"'>"+screen_name+"</a><div id='txt'>"+text+"<div class='twitter_posted_at'><span class='timeago' title='"+created_time+"'></span><i>via "+source+" </i></div></div></div>";
}

$(tdata).appendTo('#tweets');
}
});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow this works great! thank you! now i'm going to go study the code and personalize the css. Do you have a development blog or a twitter so i can follow you?

Comment: yet i am designing my blog, will let you know when i am done with it. My twitter handler is http://twitter.com/mrnayak :)

Comment: is there a way to add links to the profiles of people who are mentioned in tweets?

Comment: i'm not sure i know what you mean, like <div id='txt'>"+text+link+"... ?

Comment: something like <a href="+link">"+text+"</a>

Comment: ok so i have this code `<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.linkify_tweet = function() {
   var tweet = this.replace(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g, "$1@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2">$2</a>");
   return tweet.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g, "$1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2">$2</a>");
 };
</script>` how can I integrate this with the widget?

Comment: @Wilfred i will help you tmrw wit it, i will tweet u

Comment: so this would be perfect if it had a time ago stamp and the link highlighting. this feed code has those things, but i understand yours much better [link](http://www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery)

Comment: Well mine is simple, i think you can easily extend, Check out Timeago.js its a jQuery Plugin.

Comment: thanks i got the timeago.js to work, it was a great suggestion. i still not sure about the link highlighting

Comment: Note that this answer is no longer valid since the deprecation of the APIs used.